# Alexnet neutal network: how to decrease the consumption size of the network?

Tags: python, neural-network, caffe

I have 'caffe' built with 'CPU' support only -no GPU-; running Alexnet on a dataset of about 100mb consumes a very big portion of memory -close to 400GB-; I want to be able to run it with lesser consumption of memory.

Right now I'm running the network with a dataset way smaller -about 10 images for train and validation-; it's running good but I want to increase my dataset.

Please help me, my knowledge about AI is very shallow, and I would appreciate solutions to decrease the overall size of CPU consumption + running larger datasets.

solver.prototxt

```
net: "models/people_alexnet/train_val.prototxt"
test_iter: 100
test_interval: 200
base_lr: 0.01
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.1
stepsize: 100000
display: 20
max_iter: 450000
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
snapshot: 10000
snapshot_prefix: "models/people_alexnet/caffe_alexnet_train"
solver_mode: CPU
```

train_val.prototxt

```
name: "AlexNet"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: true
    crop_size: 227
    mean_file: "data/people/mean.binaryproto"
  }
  data_param {
    source: "examples/people/people_train_lmdb/"
    batch_size: 10
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: false
    crop_size: 227
    mean_file: "data/people/mean.binaryproto"
  }
  data_param {
    source: "examples/people/val_lmdb"
    batch_size: 5
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 96
    kernel_size: 11
    stride: 4
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
layer {
  name: "norm1"
  type: "LRN"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "norm1"
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    alpha: 0.0001
    beta: 0.75
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "norm1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 2
    kernel_size: 5
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv2"
}
layer {
  name: "norm2"
  type: "LRN"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "norm2"
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    alpha: 0.0001
    beta: 0.75
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pool2"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "norm2"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "conv3"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 384
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv3"
}
layer {
  name: "conv4"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv4"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 384
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu4"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv4"
}
layer {
  name: "conv5"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv5"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu5"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "conv5"
}
layer {
  name: "pool5"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "pool5"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc6"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "pool5"
  top: "fc6"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4096
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.005
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu6"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
}
layer {
  name: "drop6"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc7"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc7"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4096
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.005
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu7"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
}
layer {
  name: "drop7"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc8"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc8"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "fc8"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc8"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to run the network with a decreased size by decreasing "batch-size" in "train_val.prototxt":

```
  data_param {
    source: "examples/people/people_val_lmdb"
    batch_size: 2 -> #changed from 5
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
```

Now the network only requires 12GBs:

```
Memory required for data: 1236704
```